# Sliding window for streaming timeseries data -- pandas or deque?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, monitoring

I have an stream of infinite API log data that has a time column.

| url | time (unix) | status | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /api/help | 1520938502 | 200 | 1324 |
| /report/status | 1555598024 | 404 | 1434 |

I can't dump all the data into memory, so I plan on reading line by line, updating either a priority queue or dataframe (not sure which would scale better, which is why I am asking).

##### What I want to do is the following:

Store N minutes worth of lines from the file and perform a running average. If the average number of requests is above a threshold, T, then print an alert to console. Only run the alert once, then print to console again when average number of requests in an N minute interval is below T requests/second again.

**I am trying to figure out what data structure to use to perform this analysis -- my concerns are optimizing for speed and scalability.**

---

**Notes on timestamps**: The timestamps are irregular (ie it's not like I have perfectly Z entries per second), this means I can't rely on perfectly fitting X data points per data structure -- I will need to compare the time delta between the first and last data point with N, and if it's over N drop items (perhaps multiple, depending on how far in the future the latest data point to be added is from the first data point in the queue/df) from the end of the queue/df.

**Pro of using a deque/queue**

- has straightforward append/pop left properties
- is space efficient
- would be amenable to threading if I could find a usecase

**Pros of pandas df**

- has nice, fast in-built functions for creating a rolling window and performing statistical analysis on that window.
- NOTE: What I am confused about here is avoiding creating a very large dataframe by constantly appending. Oddly enough, I don't see many tutorials show how they handle this. I would like to quickly and easily delete expired data, which is why I am more in favor of a queue/deque.

Comment: Is the url, status and size data actually necessary for this problem?  Isn't it just counting timestamp occurances in a window?

Comment: No it's not necessary for this part of the problem, I was just including an example of a few of the columns from the logs. I will need some of this info for what I am building down the line because I want to, for example, report stats from specific URLs, or report unusual status codes, etc.